# Python string from list comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to get this string as a result:

```
"&markers=97,64&markers=45,84"
```

From the Python code below:

```
markers = [(97,64),(45,84)]
result = ("&markers=%s" %x for x in markers)
return result
```

How do I do this as the below does not give me the actual string?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to join your string like this:

```
markers = [(97,64),(45,84)]
result = ''.join("&markers=%s" % ','.join(map(str, x)) for x in markers)
return result
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't initially have the `','.join(map(str, x))` section in there to turn each tuple into strings. This handles varying length tuples, but if you will always have exactly 2 numbers, you might see gatto's comment below.

The explanation of what's going on is that we make a list with one item for each tuple from markers, turning the tuples into comma separated strings which we format into the `&markers=` string. This list of strings is then joined together separated by an empty string.

Comment: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: it complained it wasnt a string so i did this which also returns a generator object, not the actual string result = "".join(str(("&marker=%s" % x for x in markers)))

Comment: @gatto, unless the tuples are of variable length. see my updated answer

Answer (score 17):

In Python 3.6 you could write:

```
markers = [(97,64),(45,84)]
result = ''.join(f'&markers={pair}' for pair in markers)
return result
```

Answer (score 11):

While the first answer is doing what's expected, I'd make it a bit more "pythonic" by getting rid of `map` and nested expressions:

```
def join(seq, sep=','):
    return sep.join(str(i) for i in seq)

result = ''.join('&markers=%s' % join(m) for m in markers)
```

(if that's for urls like it seems, you can also take a look at [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode))

Comment: Not quite. Your join function will never get called. Should be without the `''.`: `result = join('&markers=%s' % join(m) for m in markers)`

Comment: @modle13 my `join` is called for each element in the loop.

Comment: This is really confusing because you're creating a new function with the same name as the built-in string method "join".

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach that hopefully makes the intent the most clear by specifying the location of each of your values explicitly:

```
markers = [(97,64),(45,84)]
print ''.join('&markers=%s,%s' % pair for pair in markers)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try creating an empty string adding to it then removing the last comma

```
result = ''

for i in a:
    result+='&markers'
    for j in i:
    result += str(j) + ','
result = result[:-1]

return result
```